# PHP Blade Foreach element in collection attribute

Tags: php, foreach, collections, laravel-blade

I have a collection with an array of product properties, most of the properties are an array of: [property_name, property_name_translated, value_of_property]

like this:

```
Product {#290 ▼
  #connection: "general"
  #table: "product"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:18 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "image" => "sensor.png"
    "url" => "senso"
    "battery" => array:2 [▼
      "value" => "Rechargable (2h to fully charge / 40h autonomy)"
      "property_trans" => "Battery"
    ]
    "compatible" => array:2 [▼
      "value" => "Andriod/iOS with Bluetooth 4.0, RookMotion Center/APP"
      "property_trans" => "Compatible"
    ]
    ...

    "height" => array:2 [▼
      "value" => "4"
      "property_trans" => "height"
    ]
    "memory" => array:2 [▼
      "value" => "Yes (8h)"
      "property_trans" => "Memory"
    ]
  ]
  #original: array:3 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "image" => "sensor.png"
    "url" => "sensor"
  ]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
```

On my blade I get the product as entity
If I print the content of entity in blade, the attributes are there in the webpage:

```
<td class="border-none">{{$entidad}}</td>
```

prints:

```
{"id":2,"image":"sensor","url":"sensor","battery":{"value":"Rechargable (2h to fully charge \/ 40h autonomy)","property_trans":"Battery"},"compatible":{"value":"Andriod\/iOS with Bluetooth 4.0, RookMotion Center\/APP","property_trans":"Compatible"}, ... "weight":{"value":"70","property_trans":"weight"},"width":{"value":"6.4","property_trans":"width"},"price":"76.90"}
```

**How can I Make a for loop to print each element of attributes??**

Printing manually each element works ok

```
// This works and shows the property name translated and its value
@if(!is_null($entidad->battery))
    <td class="border-none">{{$entidad->battery['property_trans']}}</td>
    <td class="border-none">{{$entidad->battery['value']}}</td>
@endif
```

But a for loop is not working properly

```
<tbody>                                                         
    @foreach($entidad as $property)
        <tr>
           <td>Found one prop</td>
           <td>{{$property}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach                                                             
</tbody>
```

It prints only 4 elements of the collection, but not the collection attibutes

```
+incrementing: true
+timestamps: true
+exists: true
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
```

[image]

Why I cannot loop the collection attributes?? In my controller I can access all the attributes with a foreach but here in the blade I cannot.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should cast your collection to an array using `toArray()` method first

```
<tbody>                                                         
    @foreach($entidad->toArray() as $property)
        <tr>
           <td>Found one prop</td>
           <td>{{$property}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach                                                             
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works partially. I mean, with your code I can access to the firts level of the array. Now I need to access to the array on each element of the parent array. But i need to check if the element is an array if(is_array) because I'm having an error since some elements of the array are not arrays.